# Json goes to error when I call it from other Action or view , but it succed when run directly?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, jqplot

I have an action method that in the view part I Use Json to get data from other action in my controller ,
it go to success method when i call it directly , 
(put routConfig action eqaul to this Action  )

but when i call the action from links it goes to error ,
I dont know why ?!

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PieRenderer()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetPieRenderer()
    {
        var DbResult = from d in db.Rep_TaskTypeQueuChart(0, 1)
                       select new
                       {
                           d.TaskTypeName,
                           d.WorkCount
                       };
        //return Json(DbResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return Json(DbResult);
    }
```

view:

```
<!-- CSS  -->
<link href="~/Scripts/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Scripts JS  -->

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.js"></script>
```

```
    <script>
        $.jqplot('chartdiv', [[[1, 2], [3, 5.12], [5, 13.1], [7, 33.6], [9, 85.9], [11, 219.9]]]);

        $(document).ready(function () {

            // $.jqplot('chartdiv3', [[[1, 2], [3, 5.12], [5, 13.1], [7, 33.6], [9, 85.9], [11, 219.9]]]);               
            //$.ajax(alert('Hiiiiiiiii'));                //alert('111')
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Cartable/GetPieRenderer",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnError
            });

            function OnSuccess(response) {

                var aData = response;
                var dataArray = [];

                $.each(aData, function (i, item) {
                    dataArray.push([item.TaskTypeName, item.WorkCount]);
                    alert(item.TaskTypeName);
                });



                var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chartdiv3', [dataArray],
                    {
                        seriesDefaults: {
                            // Make this a pie chart.
                            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                            rendererOptions: {
                                sliceMargin: 4,
                                // Put data labels on the pie slices.

                                showDataLabels: true
                            }
                        },
                        legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }
                    }
                );

            }
            function OnError(response) {
                alert("Error !");
                alert(response.toString());
            }


        });

    </script>
</div>
```

If I change RoutConfig action="PieRenderer" it shows the result.
but if i run the main dashboard view , and there i had a actinlink or a href to PieRenderer method , it goes to error method ()...

Answer (score 0):

I Find the answer , the problem because of this part :
url: "Cartable/GetPieRenderer"

it should be change like this :
url: "/Cartable/GetPieRenderer",